# Problem render a function on a Django file

Tags: python, django, websocket

Hello Friends I have this program in views.py Im using django with websockets to take the RFID data from antenna and send to my server.
The problem is that in the function

```
def tag_seen_callback(llrpMsg):
    """Function to run each time the reader reports seeing tags."""
    global numtags
    tags = llrpMsg.msgdict['RO_ACCESS_REPORT']['TagReportData']
    if len(tags):
        logger.info('saw tag(s): %s', pprint.pformat(tags))
        for tag in tags:
            numtags += tag['TagSeenCount'][0]
    else:
        logger.info('no tags seen')
        return
```

I cant renderd to send the data to the websocket in my script on html file I trie with all but everytime its the same error

### This is my entire code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
from django.template import Template,Context
from django.template import loader

import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', '..')))

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from logging import getLogger, INFO, Formatter, StreamHandler, WARN
from sllurp.llrp import LLRP_PORT, LLRPClientFactory
import smokesignal
from twisted.internet import reactor
from sllurp.util import monotonic

'''
Sllurp/Tornado Example
This file contains an example showing how to use Sllurp with Tornado
to update a web page via websockets when rfid tags are seen.
'''
numtags = 0
start_time = None

def tag_seen_callback(llrpMsg):
    """Function to run each time the reader reports seeing tags."""
    global numtags
    tags = llrpMsg.msgdict['RO_ACCESS_REPORT']['TagReportData']
    if len(tags):
        logger.info('saw tag(s): %s', pprint.pformat(tags))
        for tag in tags:
            numtags += tag['TagSeenCount'][0]
    else:
        logger.info('no tags seen')
        return

def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Simple RFID Reader Inventory')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='hostname or IP address of RFID reader',
                        nargs='*')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=LLRP_PORT, type=int,
                        help='port to connect to (default {})'.format(LLRP_PORT))
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--report-every-n-tags', default=1, type=int,
                        dest='every_n', metavar='N', help='issue a TagReport every N tags')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--antennas', default='1',
                        help='comma-separated list of antennas to enable')
    parser.add_argument('-X', '--tx-power', default=0, type=int,
                        dest='tx_power', help='Transmit power (default 0=max power)')
    parser.add_argument('-M', '--modulation', default='M8',
                        help='modulation (default M8)')
    parser.add_argument('-T', '--tari', default=0, type=int,
                        help='Tari value (default 0=auto)')
    return parser.parse_args()


def polite_shutdown(factory):
    return factory.politeShutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up tornado to use reactor
    setup_logging()
    # Set up tornado to use reactor
    TwistedIOLoop().install()
    # Set up web server

    # Load Sllurp config
    args = parse_args()

    enabled_antennas = list(
        map(lambda x: int(x.strip()), args.antennas.split(',')))

    # Create Clients and set them to connect
    fac = LLRPClientFactory(report_every_n_tags=args.every_n,
                            antennas=enabled_antennas,
                            tx_power=args.tx_power,
                            #modulation=args.modulation,
                            start_inventory=True,
                            tari=args.tari,
                            tag_content_selector={
                                'EnableROSpecID': False,
                                'EnableSpecIndex': False,
                                'EnableInventoryParameterSpecID': False,
                                'EnableAntennaID': True,
                                'EnableChannelIndex': False,
                                'EnablePeakRSSI': True,
                                'EnableFirstSeenTimestamp': False,
                                'EnableLastSeenTimestamp': True,
                                'EnableTagSeenCount': True,
                                'EnableAccessSpecID': False,
                            })
    fac.addTagReportCallback(tag_seen_callback)
    #for host in args.host:
    reactor.connectTCP('192.168.1.12', 5084, fac)

    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', polite_shutdown, fac)
   #     reactor.connectTCP('192.168.1.13',5084, factory)
    start_time = monotonic()
    # Start server & connect to readers
    reactor.run()

def index(request,*args):
    #print(numtags)
   #data={'stock1':{'name':'Stock1','opening':45346,'closing':1234,'currentVal':56},
    #'stock2':{'name':'Stock2','opening':1889,'closing':234235,'currentVal':56},
    #'stock3':{'name':'Stock3','opening':1883,'closing':5346,'currentVal':56},
    #'stock4':{'name':'Stock4','opening':1884,'closing':56457,'currentVal':56},
    #'stock5':{'name':'Stock5','opening':1881,'closing':56457,'currentVal':56},
    
    #}

    context={'start_time':start_time}
    #context={'data':data,'tableheader':['name','opening','closing','currentVal']}

    return render(request,"index.html",context)


----------
```

Comment: "*but everytime its the same error*". What error? Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: TypeError: tag_seen_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'llrpMsg'